# NODE JS APP: What does this notation mean?

Tags: node.js, express

I've picked up a project from another developer, uses the typical MEAN stack with the entry point being server.js.

Now, in server.js, the module that does:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app     = express();
var passport = require('passport');
```

There are another 2 lines of code that look like they are doing some sort of routing but I can't figure out what it actually means:

```
require('./routes.js')(app, passport);
require('./apiRequest/authenticate')(app, passport);
```

I'm confused because it looks like `require()` is called from the global scope, whereas all the other routing methods are called off app, i.e `app.use()`. Can someone explain what the sets of parameters mean, and why are there two sets also where is `require()` called from, is it provided by Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`routes.js` and `apiRequest/authenticate` are two local (project) modules / js files that are basically required here.

`express` and `passport` are node modules/libraries that are provided from npm_modules, via node module resolution.

`app` is simply an express instance created by invoking the express module/default function.

The parameters passed to the required local modules (routes and authenticate) are just parameters passed to those modules (default exported function) that can be used further in those files (e.g. if you look in routes.js you will probably see that they use `app.use(...`, where app is given as param as well as the passport module)

To explain the syntax `require('./routes.js')(app, passport);` more clearly:

1. `require` - node OOB function for importing modules into the current file/module
2. `require('./routes.js')` resolves the default export from the routes.js file which in this case is a function
3. `...(app, passport)` this function (from above point) is then invoked with the provided params (which were previously defined here - i.e. imported with require)

Comment: Okay, does that mean in point 3, **this function is invoked with the provided params** that there can be any number of params? or can there only be 2, and what is the actual function that these are the params for, is it 'require()'?

Comment: The function is the one defined in the 'routes.js' file (which should be a project file in the same folder as the file where the code you mentioned is)  - there will be a function defined which is exported, and it's that function that is invoked here. The number of expected params can only be seen if you take a look at that file, as it depends how many that exported function expects and what it does with them. Note that in JS functions do not have a static number of required params, it's generally convention-based how many to provide, which are optional, etc.